# Получение ссылки на объект Class класса String

Tags: java, строки, классы

Есть следующее тестовое задание:

> Укажите корректные способы получения ссылки на объект Class класса String.
>
> 1. Невозможно получить ссылку на объект Class класса String, т.к. данный класс является final;
> 2. String.class;
> 3. Class.forName("java.lang.String")
> 4. new String.getClass()

Склоняюсь к 2) и 4), но не уверен.

Comment: А почему бы не попробовать составить программу? И прогнать все варианты?

Comment: `new String.getClass()` - это даже не скомпилируется. Может, там всё-таки было `new String().getClass()`?

Comment: всё верно, там было new String().getClass()

Comment: Вопросы с несколькими вариантами ответов, пожалуй, оффтоп. Каждый из вариантов следует разбирать отдельно. Иначе получается четыре вопроса в одном. P.S. Свой вопрос можно исправить с помощью кнопки «править»

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода с комментариями:

```
/*
Примечание:

Пакет java.lang.ref
 Помимо обыкновенных ссылок, известных так же как Strong References (сильные ссылки), 
в Java представлен пакет java.lang.ref, содержащий реализации Soft (мягких), 
Week (слабых) и Phantom (фантомных) ссылок, которые по-разному обрабатываются 
сборщиком мусора и предоставляют пользователю возможность более гибко работать с памятью.
 */
package regObjClass;

import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class RefObjClassString {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
     Class c = Class.forName("java.lang.String"); //возвращает экземпляр класса
     //Если у нас есть класс, для которого в момент компиляции известен тип то
     Class strClass = String.class;

     /* мягкие и фантомные ссылки*/
    /* создание мягкой ссылки */
    SoftReference<String> softRefStr = new SoftReference<String>(new String("SoftRef"));

   ReferenceQueue<String> queue = new ReferenceQueue<String>(); //создание очереди 
   /*создание фантомной ссылки*/
   PhantomReference<String> ref = new PhantomReference<String>(new String("Фантом"), queue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. получается, что верными будут ответы 2), 3), 4)?

Comment: Метод getClass() позволяет получить тип данного объекта.

Comment: Метод getClass() позволяет получить тип данного объекта. На мой взгляд ответы 2) 3) правильные.  Мой код выше, это только дополнение  к ответу.  Но всё равно вопрос требует уточнений, контекста использования "корректных" способов получения ссылки и версии java. String s = String.class.newInstance(); // Создать новый объект класса String. Некоторые связанные темы это: Reflection, ClassLoader

Comment: А причем здесь мягкие и фантомные ссылки?

Comment: Чтобы дать более полный ответ на вопрос. Документация по ссылкам: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html 
Виды ссылок на объекты: http://www.quizful.net/post/java_reference_types
Ссылка (Java): http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/Ссылка_(Java)